# how to dynamically change Header Value of Gridview Horizontally from database in asp.net using VB code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, header

In my current code, this is the initial User Interface of my gridview:
http://prntscr.com/4sb8az

And I want/need to make it look like this: http://prntscr.com/4skhmv

All of the data are coming from a Stored Procedure using SQL Server. I cannot use Pivot in the database because i should not mess up with the Stored Procedure. How can i make the dates display on my Grid View Horizontally with the specific results under the dates(pls refer to the links above), while my First 2 Columns are displayed Vertically? Can Somebody help me? Thanks in advance. Ive already tried using HeaderTemplate but it is not working so i reverted back my code to its original.

This is my code(This is not the whole code i get only the impt. ones)

```
Private Sub LoadGrid()
    Dim o_Dataset As New DataSet()

    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(DataSource.ConnectionString)
        Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand()
            Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "Station.dbo.sp_Nurse_GetPatient_LabResult_NormalValues_Tabular_New"
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@HospNum", Session.Item("HospNum")))
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn
            sqlConn.Open()
            Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
            sqlReader.Close()
            sqlAdapter.Fill(o_Dataset)
            grdReports_H.DataSource = o_Dataset.Tables(0)
            grdReports_H.DataBind()
            GroupGridView(grdReports_H.Rows, 0, 3)
            sqlConn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

ASPX FILE:

```
    <asp:GridView   OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound_H" ID="grdReports_H" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"   CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" style="text-align: center">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

                            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle  BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

       <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="labsectionid" HeaderText="SectionID_A" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section"  ItemStyle-Width="40px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Exam" HeaderText="Exam" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="NormalValue" HeaderText="Normal Values" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Result" HeaderText="Result" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="ResultDate" HeaderText="ResultDate" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
        </Columns>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use repeater instead of gridview.

Comment: how can i achieve this sir using Repeater?

Comment: Yes, if you have to change the header dynamically, repeater would be better, you can even use header template for this matter

Comment: I can change the header dynamically and make it horizontal (like in the pic) using repeater?

Comment: Oh my bad, i thought it was a vertical table, in this case, you'll end up sacrificing performance a bit, but use datalist. Datalist does not need to be vertical like repeater.

Comment: Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/79k821wc(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hmm i've already tried using DataList but it seems that it makes the whole table horizontal, not a specifc column only. Because what i need to do is my first 3 columns is vertical, but the dates should be horizontal. Kindly check the picture on the link above i cant explain it thoroughly.

Comment: Can you show how the tables are organized? Or at least the outpu of the sproc.

Comment: This is my current output. http://prntscr.com/4sb8az

Comment: And i want to make it like this http://prntscr.com/4skhmv (sorry for my Paint skills lol)

Comment: Just build a <table>. Not everything has to be an asp.net server control. Especially if the data is read only.